# Inserting a single row with large number of columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

I have a huge form that has around 110 <del>fields</del> columns (single row) that need to be saved in a database.

What is the best approach to insert these many columns into the database using ADO.NET?

I don't think I should be using an insert statement like this, since the query would be very large due to the number of fields.

```
conn.Open();
string insertString = @"
    insert into Categories (CategoryName, Description)
    values ('Miscellaneous', 'Whatever doesn''t fit elsewhere')";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertString, conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I think of dumping the data into temp file and then adding them into a datatable and then inserting them into database using SqlBulkCopy.

Is there a better approach? How would you handle this situation?

Comment: If your table also has ~110 fields, I'm sorry, but you're doing it wrong. Refactor / normalize into several tables and do multiple related `INSERT` statements.

Comment: How many rows will you be adding at a single time?  Is it just a single row with 110 columns, or are we talking a lot of rows at one time?

Comment: @Yuck: I can't help it. I wish I could take time to do that. But that's unfortunately not something I can control at the moment.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson: This will be a web page where users fill their data in most of the fields. Once they submit the data, it will be put in database. A rough estimate is around 1500 users over a period of three days who will be using the form.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson: To answer you precisely, one row per submission, each row contains 110 fields, a total of 1500 users who will access the form.

Comment: @KishorNanda When the user submits the form, does it need to be instantly added to the database, or were you thinking of building up the temp file and then bulk loading it at the end of the 3 days?

Comment: It needs to be added instantly.

Comment: You should do a regular insert. Use bulk copy when you have a lot of rows that needs to be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there isn't a good shortcut for inserting this number of columns, but using parameters will likely save some debugging time. By using parameters you do not need to worry about things likes apostrophes in strings and type conversions. Here's a sample:

```
public static void TryThis()
{
  try
  {
    using  (SqlConnection  con = new SqlConnection())
    {
      con.ConnectionString = "YourConnectionString";
      con.Open();
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
      cmd.Connection = con;
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Categories (CategoryName, Description)  VALUES (@CategoryName, @Description)";
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CategoryName", "Miscellaneous");
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Description", "Whatever doesn't fit elsewhere");
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
  }
}
```